# Split unsymmetrical XML into multiple XMLs

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have to split an unsymmetrical xml on 'Trade' element using java

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<BookingRequest>      
   <Id>1234</Id>
   <App>Pan</App>
   <Parties>
     <Party>1</Party>
     <Party>2</Party>
   </Parties>
   <Contract>
      <Trades>
        <Trade>
            <Detail>100</Detail>
            <Location>
                <Num>10001</Num>
            </Location>
         </Trade>           
         <Trade>
            <Detail>101</Detail>
            <Location>
                <Num>10002</Num>
            </Location>
        </Trade>
      </Trades>
   </Contract>
</BookingRequest>
```

My requirement is post split there should be 2 files:

FILE 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<BookingRequest>      
   <Id>1234</Id>
   <App>Pan</App>
   <Parties>
     <Party>1</Party>
     <Party>2</Party>
   </Parties>
   <Contract>
      <Trades>
        <Trade>
            <Detail>100</Detail>
            <Location>
                <Num>10001</Num>
            </Location>
        </Trade>
      </Trades>
   </Contract>
</BookingRequest>
```

FILE 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<BookingRequest>      
   <Id>1234</Id>
   <App>Pan</App>
   <Parties>
     <Party>1</Party>
     <Party>2</Party>
   </Parties>
   <Contract>
      <Trades>
        <Trade>
            <Detail>101</Detail>
            <Location>
                <Num>10002</Num>
            </Location>
         </Trade>
      </Trades>
   </Contract>
</BookingRequest>
```

Could someone help me in doing this kind of splitting (preferably using DOM/XPath and NOT XSLT)

Comment: were you try with org.w3c.dom.Document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse("booking-request.xml");
Element bookingRequest = doc.getDocumentElement();
Element contract = (Element)bookingRequest.getElementsByTagName("Contract").item(0);
Element trades = (Element)contract.getElementsByTagName("Trades").item(0);

List<Element> tradeList = new ArrayList<Element>();
NodeList nodeList = trades.getElementsByTagName("Trade");
for(int i=0; i<nodeList.getLength(); i++)
    tradeList.add((Element)nodeList.item(i));

Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
int i = 0;
for(Element trade: tradeList){
    // remove all children of <Trades>
    while(trades.getFirstChild()!=null)
        trades.removeChild(trades.getFirstChild());

    trades.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("\n            "));
    trades.appendChild(trade);
    trades.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("\n        "));
    ++i;
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(new File("trade"+i+".xml")));
}
```

Comment: Hi Santhosh. Just did. Thanks